# AngularJS data usage pattern

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and in my application I am making a REST API call and the returned response is stored as a model object. For my view, I have created a seperate view model object since the response from the API cannot be as such used in the UI.

Is this a right approach? Note that I am using two different models -> One gets data from the server and other is used as UI backing model. This is similar to a backing bean and DAO objects in Java frameworks.

Please advise whether this approach is fine or should it be changed. If so how?

**Update**
Have illustrated the issue in 
http://jsfiddle.net/LGEKX/

```
function mycontroller($scope){
//The view model is populated by a seperate method
var viewmodel = populateViewModel();
$scope.viewmodel = viewmodel;
}

function populateViewModel(){
//Call service to update local model
var backendModel = serviceCall();
//Invoke conversion service
var converteModel = convertBackEndModel(backendModel);
}

function serviceCall(){
//Service method calls server side API and the data returned is returned in success     callback
 $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    return data;
 }).
 error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  ...
  });

 }

 function convertBackEndModel(data){
   //This takes the data returned from API call as input and creates a view model
  //which will be used for angularjs view (in HTML)
var viewModel = {};
 viewModel.name = backendModel.backendName;
 //Though this is simple, actual code has lots of logic which basically converts one    JSON structure to another
 }
```

and in my HTML

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="mycontroller">
    <!-- Binding to viewmodel from the HTML-->
    <div ng-model="viewmodel.name"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without any code and further explanation this question is hard to understand for some one else.

Comment: AngularJS does work differently than traditional Java/.NET apps (MVC or MVVM). It is not at all necessary to have a separate set of classes. JavaScript is a dynamic language and it is effortless to attach additional properties to your model without getting in your way to manage 2 way binding between the view and the controller. You can directly use the response from the service.
Please check some documentation on AngularJS and some nice videos on Youtube to get a feel of usage patterns.

Comment: @Ketan I understand that we can dynamically attach properties to the model. But can you please elaborate the design pattern to be followed here. Normally I seperate out the UI model and the persistence layer model and have a data transfer object which does the conversion between the same in the case of server side languages. I understand I can skip it and directly bind to same model but in my case I will prefer a seperate model for the view. I need to know whether this is a preferred practice. Please advis

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple pattern using $http to make a call to the server and then the html to bind to the scope variable

```
  $http({
               url: "http://localhost/people/1"
           }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               if (data) {
                   $scope.person = data;
               }
           });



<div>{{person.firstName}}</div> <!-- one way -->
<input ng-model='person.firstName' /> <!-- two way -->
```

The only reason I think you might need a separate DTO is if the GET and PUT services use different classes, in that case you will need to massage the data.

Comment: I just saw your update. As I mentioned above there is really no need to create a separate VM and it is not a required pattern in AngularJS nor it is a best practice.